# Don't make the slug column unique for all the users (authors)

Tags: php, laravel

I have the `User` and `Post` models in the project. I want to make the `slug` column from `Post` unique but not when updating the `post`. I found this URL `https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-unique` from one of the answers.

I found a solution from the above URL `'slug' => 'unique:posts,slug,'.auth()->id().',user_id'` but this is not exactly what I want. That makes the column not unique only for one user with provided id.

In my case, I want all **the admin users** to be able to edit **editors' or authors' posts** without changing the **slugs** whenever they do.

Validation codes inside update method.

```
$request->validate([
    'title'             => 'required|string|max:255',
    'slug'              => 'required|string|max:255|unique:posts,slug,'.auth()->id().',user_id',
    'featured_img'      => 'nullable|max:1024|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg',
    'excerpt'           => 'nullable|string|max:225',
    'body'              => 'nullable',
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Post` rather than a `User` when specifying the criteria for `unique`.

```
// include a use statement for Rule
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

'slug' => [
    'required',
    'string',
    'max:255',
    Rule::unique('posts')->ignore($post->id)
]
```

Where `$post` in the above is the `$post` object you're working with in the `update` function.

The above obviously doesn't scope the rule to just `admins`, but you generally have separate routes/controllers for `admin` related functionality. Alternatively, you can conditionally include the rule.

Comment: I tried yours in my controller but doesn't work.

This is how I validated the `slug` in my controller. `'slug' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:posts,slug,'. auth()->id().',user_id'` 

Can you please let me know how to combine yours and current validation all together and make it work?

Comment: @Frank I have updated my answer for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Peppermintology but I think something is still missing. `Class "App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Illuminate\Validation\Rule" not found` error has been shown.

I have updated my question with the codes of how I have validated that. If I fireplace yours in the `slug`, I receive the above error.

Comment: @Frank Can you show **exactly** how you used my suggestion please?

Comment: Here is how I added that. I didn't import or use `Rule` at the top of the file since it looks like the whole path.

```$request->validate([
     'slug' => [
         'required',
         'string',
         'max:255',
         Illuminate\Validation\Rule::unique('posts')->ignore($post->id)
      ], 
]);```

Comment: @Frank You shouldn't have to if you've used the FQN. What version of Laravel are you using? Here is a [sandbox](https://phpsandbox.io/n/shrill-sea-kz1b-myij9) showing the principle working in isolation as proof of concept.

Comment: I am working on Laravel 9.

Comment: @Frank I've updated my answer to include a `use` statement, however, it really shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: It works when using it at the top of the controller. Thanks.

Comment: @Frank How strange. Pleased its working for you though after all that!